# Find the elements dynamically in header and click on them to verify in python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation

This is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class Runfftest():
    def test(self):
        """
        Inistitate the ff browser
        launch the browser
        :return:
        """
        baseUrl = "https://letskodeit.teachable.com/p/practice"
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver")
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get(baseUrl)
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)

        header_by_xpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='navbar']")
        links_in_header = header_by_xpath.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"a")
        size_of_links = len(links_in_header)
        print(size_of_links)

        for linkinheader in links_in_header:
            linkinheader.click()


ff = Runfftest()
ff.test()
```

I am able to find a element and also click on it but when I do, it throws an error.

Comment: which error ? please also post the error in your question.

Comment: Where is your error? Post it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first click your error is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Which means that after click you've got brand new html page and all the elements from the old page are stale (don't exist on the new page).

Note that **links_in_header** list contains a list of elements but not links (urls) themselves. So you could just do something like this (instead of clicking):

```
links_in_header = header_by_xpath.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"a")
# get urls from tags
links_in_header = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in links_in_header]
for linkinheader in links_in_header:
    driver.get(linkinheader)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I don't understand one thing, you find the element by xpath, why after you search the header and you try to click in the header?

Follow this code, it works;
ps you are even selecting a wrong xpath:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class Runfftest():
    def test(self):
        """
        Inistitate the ff browser
        launch the browser
        :return:
        """
        baseUrl = "https://letskodeit.teachable.com/p/practice"
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver")
        driver.get(baseUrl)
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        header_by_xpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='navbar']/div/div/a")
        header_by_xpath.click()

ff = Runfftest()
ff.test()
```

PS: remember to close the browser when you finish:

```
driver.close()
```